# C# MongoDB update object from oplog

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

What I have is a MongoDB which contains a collection of products. Lets say each product has the following structure:

```
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
public string label { get; set; }
public List<IngredientsModel> ingredients { get; set; }
```

Now my C# program gets notified via the oplog if there was a change. This oplog looks like this:

```
{ 
"ts" : Timestamp(1425392023, 1), 
"h" : NumberLong("-7452324865462273810"), 
"v" : 2, 
"op" : "u", 
"ns" : "coll.products", 
"o2" : { "_id" : ObjectId("54f5b87cd4c6959bd3ecf2d6") }, 
"o" : { "$set" : { "ingredients.1.ingredid" : "54f5c117d4c6959bd3ecf2e8" } } 
}
```

When my application starts I create a list of products which I get from the MongoDB. I just use  products.findAll() and the put them in a List<'products>

I have several clients connected to the MongoDB and every client gets notified via oplog.

Now I want to update my local lists without querying the MongoDB since I have all the information needed to update my local products already in the oplog.

My question is now: How to do that?

My approach is the following:

1. Deserialize the object to Json

`var prodjson= Product[0].ToJson<ProductModel>();`

2. Convert Json to BsonDocument

`var prodbson= BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(prodjson);`

3. Apply the "o" key from the oplog to the prodbson

`"o" : { "$set" : { "ingredients.1.ingredid" : "54f5c117d4c6959bd3ecf2e8" } }
NO IDEA`

Comment: You do an update operation.  Update takes query and update parts - query is what you get as the "o2" field, update part is what you get as "o" field.  Oh, sorry, do you mean you maintain this list in memory, and not in another MongoDB collection?

Comment: exactly I keep it in memory, otherwise you would be 100% right.

Comment: What is the bettery way? Create a local copy of the MongoDB or keep data in memory.

Comment: do you need to change it other than from the oplog? if not local copy can just be secondary that you read from...

Comment: The MongoDB is the basis of two clients. The MongoDB does hold products and lists of products. What I have to do is share does lists between the two clients. This is done via the MongoDB. So I need to update lists from the current client and the other client.